# How strip python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a quiz code for school. The code iterates over a text file and loads the questions and answers from it. The user will select a difficulty to do the quiz on. The number of options for answers will vary depending on the difficulty. I have split each question and possible answer in the text file with commas.

```
from random import shuffle

file = open("maths.txt" , "r")
for line in file:
    question = line.split(",")
    print(question[0])
    if difficulty in ("e", "E"):
        options = (question[1], question[2])

    if difficulty in ("m", "M"):
        options = (question[1], question[2], question[3])

    if difficulty in("h", "H"):
        options = (question[1], question[2], question[3], question[4])

    options = list(options)
    shuffle(options)
    print(options)

    answer = input("Please enter answer: ")

    if answer in (question[1]):
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("incorrect")
  file.close()
```

This is what a line of the text file would look like:
Question 1. What is 4+5?,9,10,20,11

The first option (question[1]) will always be the correct answer, therefore I would like to shuffle the options. With this code the options are outputted with square brackets, newline characters and quotation marks. Does anyone know how I can strip these? I tried to use: `line.split(",").strip()` however this seemed to do nothing at all. Thanks

Comment: What's the expected output? Also update this `if difficulty in ("m","M""):`

Comment: `line.split(",").strip()` should raise an error, not do nothing. What do the contents of `maths.txt` look like?

Comment: Please add that to the question in a code block.

Comment: You should use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in the standard library to read `maths.txt` so the lines are split correctly. That would take care of newlines and correctly handle commas in the text of the answers.

Comment: I find the question title amusing.

Comment: Added what a line of the file would look like in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to print a `list` object. Instead, you should print each option. you'd probably be better printing some formatting around it:

```
for option_num, option in enumerate(options):
    print("{} - {}").format(option_num, option)
```

please read about `enumerate` and `format` to understand exactly what happens here

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
from random import shuffle
def maths_questions():
  file = open("maths.txt" , "r")
  for line in file:
    question = line.strip().split(",") # every line in file contains newline. add str.strip() to remove it
    print(question[0])

    if difficulty in ("e","E"):
        options = [question[1],question[2]]
    elif difficulty in ("m","M"):
        options = [question[1],question[2],question[3]]
    elif difficulty in("h","H"):
        options = [question[1],question[2],question[3],question[4]]
    # why to create tuple and then convert to list? create list directly

    shuffle(options) #shuffle list
    print("Options: ", ", ".join(options)) # will print "Options: opt1, opt2, opt3" for M difficulty

    answer=input("Please enter answer: ")

    if answer in (question[1]):
            print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect, please try again...")
  file.close()
```

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> `str.join(iterable)`
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable. A TypeError will be raised if there are any non-string values in iterable, including bytes objects. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
for option in options:
    print(option)
```

Comment: Needs a `.strip()` in there somewhere

Comment: @Blurp I believe the commas and brackets mentioned are actually from Python's way of printing a list, and that's why the answer was much simpler than it seemed. No strip was needed

Comment: Wouldn't the last option have a newline that would need to be stripped? And the options might have leading and trailing whitespace. That's why I suggested using the `csv` module to read the file above.

Answer (score 1):

To remove characters from a string, use `.rstrip("put text to remove here")` to remove characters from the right end of the string and `.lstrip("text to remove")` to remove characters from the left of the string.